# MariaDB-Statement in Bash here-Document of a Procedure-Block throws ERROR 1064 (42000)

Tags: bash, stored-procedures, mariadb, heredoc

I like to write a [mysql-procedure](/questions/tagged/mysql-procedure) via [bash-script](/questions/tagged/bash-script) in a [here-document](/questions/tagged/here-document).
EOF is in single-quotes so the bash do not expand variables.

Problem:
If i write a statement in the PROCEDURE BEGIN/END;-Block e.g. SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mysql.user - now it is commented - i get the error:
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 6: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4

Does anybody know how to solve it?

Code:

```
#!/bin/bash

function cp() {

mysql --verbose --line-numbers -uxxx -pxxx << 'EOF'

use mysql;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mysql.user; 

drop PROCEDURE if exists test;
create PROCEDURE `test` ()
BEGIN
-- SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mysql.user
END;

EOF
}
```

Output:

```
xxx:~# . querylog.sh cp
--------------
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mysql.user
--------------

COUNT(*)
13
--------------
drop PROCEDURE if exists test
--------------

--------------
create PROCEDURE `test` ()
BEGIN

END
--------------
```

Several tests in modifying the Bash-Script and on MySQL Workbench.
I expect no error.

Comment: You need to use the `DELIMITER` directive, just like you would if you were doing this interactively.

Comment: @Barmar, thanks for answer - but it is the same error.

function cp() {

mysql --verbose --line-numbers  -uxxx -pxxx << 'EOF'


use mysql;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mysql.user; 

drop PROCEDURE if exists test;

DELIMITER //

create PROCEDURE `test` ()
BEGIN
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mysql.user
END //

DELIMITER ;

EOF
}

Comment: You're missing the `;` at the end of the `SELECT` statement.

Comment: `code` # mysql --verbose --line-numbers  -uxxx -pxxx << 'EOF'
use mysql;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mysql.user; 

drop PROCEDURE if exists test;

DELIMITER //

create PROCEDURE `test` ()
BEGIN

if (1 > 0) then
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mysql.user;
end if; 

END //

DELIMITER ;

EOF
}

Comment: Don't put code in comments. If you have more to add to the question, click the `Edit` button and add it.